# Incrementing pointers correctly?

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, increment

I was using a char* array to copy parts of a string into another char* array, and I was wondering if doing this

```
do {
    *pntr1++ = *pntr2++
} while (*pntr2 != '\0');
```

is the same thing as

```
do
{
    *indPtr = *wordPtr;
    indPtr++;
    wordPtr++;
} while (*wordPtr != '\0');
```

or will I end up skipping an index from using the first method?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: @RogerRowland in cases of possible undefined behavior, relying on "what happened" in one specific instance can be a bad idea.

Comment: Yes both are same: I will prefer just `while(*pntr1++ = *pntr2++);`

Comment: @DavidBrown you're reading too much into my question. A simple test would show any inherent difference, and apart from the lack of a null check on the input in both cases, there's no real "undefined behaviour" involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the two are equivalent. A post-increment means the value *before* the increment is used in that expression, and the increment happens sometime before the sequence point at the end of the expression (or, in C++ terminology, "is sequenced before" the next expression).

Therefore, in both cases, the assignment uses the values of the pointers *before* they're incremented, and the comparison to `\0` uses the value of the pointer *after* it's been incremented.

If you expect this to copy a string, that does lead to a problem: at least in the code you've shown, the `\0` that terminates the (presumed) string won't get copied (though you could add code afterwards to terminate the destination string).

Comment: yes, I just ran into that problem, the loop keeps going till there are no memory addresses from the array because the incrementing statements skip the '\0'. Is there any way avoid this will still copying the array?

Comment: @Bbvarghe: You usually want something like `while ((*d++ = *s++) != '\0') {}` so you copy a byte and immediately check that byte's value, and break out of the loop if it's your terminator.

Comment: how can the statement `*d++ = *s++` be compared to `'\0'`?

Comment: @Bbvarghe: an assignment is an expression that produces a result (the value that was assigned).

Answer (score 2):

The operator `++` when used like `a++` first returns the value of `a` and then increments it.

So, the codes

```
*a++ = *b++
```

and

```
*a = *b;
a++;
b++;
```

are equivalents.